# Make playlist in python for Ads player

Tags: python, playlist

I have an array of:

`filename,number of times to show it`

Example:

```
video1.mp4,50
video2.mp4,100
video3.mp4,50
video4.mp4,150
```

What's the best way to create a playlist file, like:

```
video4
video2
video4
video1
video2
video3
video4
```

Maybe smth like:

take max show_times variable = it is a number of show blocks and try to make each block like:

> video_files_list = ((file1,50),(file2,100),(file3,300))
>
> playlist = []
>
> for i =0 to max_show_times:  // max_show_times = 300
>
> for k in video_files_list:
>
> ```
>   if i % (max_show_times/(max_show_times/k[1])) ==0:
> ```
>
> // k[1] - for file1 is 50, for file2 is 100
>
> ```
>          playlist.add(k[0])
> ```

Comment: Valeriy, what is the logic behind the order of expected playlist ?

Comment: The logic is to try avoid things like: video1 video1 video1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You algorithm can be implemented in a such way

```
from itertools import imap

def generate_playlist(pairs):
  '''
  @param pairs: list of pairs, first element is a file name, second - repetition amount
  @return: generator for playlist items
  '''
  max_show_times = max(imap(second, pairs))
  for i in xrange(max_show_times):
    for file_path, repetition_count in pairs:
      if i % (max_show_times / repetition_count) == 0:  
           yield file_path

def second(col):
  if col and len(col) > 1:
    return col[1]

playlist = generate_playlist(file_to_count_pairs)
playlist = imap(get_file_name_without_ext, playlist)
```